# run the powershell script so it checks and mails the faults

Tags: powershell, office365

I am running an office 365 database of a lot of members, each in one of a bunch of groups. I used to check the groups and users by hand but there are too many members now to be able to do that efficiently. now I have found a powershell script somewhere on github but it looks as if it just does checking and displaying in powershell. 
Is there a way to have a script compare the users and groups and if a user is in a group he does not belong in send a mail to the admin mail in the domain?
if this makes any sense...

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code to send an email in powershell.

```
$smtpServer = "mailserver.com"
$From = "from@mailserver.com"
$To = "to@example.com"
$Subject = "example"
$body = "test"
send-mailmessage -to $To -from $From -subject $Subject -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Port 25
```

Comment: With [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) the parameters are easier to define/read/pass.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you, I didn't know that was possible.